# Python Socket Server and C# Unity Client

Tags: c#, python, sockets, tcp, unity-game-engine

We're trying to connect a Python Server with socket with not blocking TCP. We tried with other clients and works like a charm.

```
server = MyTCPServer((ip_localhost, port), MyTCPServerHandler)
server.socket.setblocking(0)
```

In the other side, we have a c# unity client like this ( we tried with a lot of async implementations )

```
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback,port));
        client.Blocking = false;

        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketAsyncData = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        string a = @"{""json"":""json_data""}";
        _recieveBuffer = GetBytes(a);
        socketAsyncData.SetBuffer(_recieveBuffer,0,_recieveBuffer.Length);
        client.SendAsync(socketAsyncData);
```

Every time the c# client tries to send data :
   [ErrorNo 10035] 'The socket operation could not complete without blocking')

We've tried with :

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/c-tcp-ip-socket-how-to-receive-from-server.227259/#post-1513674

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

But no result.

Anyone knows how to implement a not blocking socket in c#?

Thanks.

Comment: Please use the unity3d tag, when referring to the game engine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make c# in Unity communicate with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57080210/1092820)