# Is possible to transform feature maps in bytes?

Tags: python, arrays, unity-game-engine, deep-learning

**Python 3.6**

**Unity 2019**

I am trying to find the best solution to transfer feature maps data to unity.

I want to send data in bytes. However i did not find how to encode it  to bytes  and after that to decode it in unity.

Basically is a 4d array that needs to be converted in byte based on how i understand it

Python piece

```
for fmap in feature_maps:
            bytes = []
            bytes.append(fmap)
            arrays_of_features.append(bytes)

        data = np.array(arrays_of_features, dtype=float) # this is not working because of the fact is multidimensional array apparently. 
        print(fmap)
        c.sendall(data.tobytes())
```

UNity piece:
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4000];
        int idxUsedBytes = client.Receive(bytes);

```
    floatsReceived = new float[idxUsedBytes / 4];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, floatsReceived, 0, idxUsedBytes);
    print(floatsReceived[0]);
```

Inspiration: [How to make c# in Unity communicate with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080210/how-to-make-c-sharp-in-unity-communicate-with-python)

A feature map looks something like this:

```
[[[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.         12.569366
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          4.421044
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.19193476
 0.        ]
...
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]]

[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.         12.910363
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          3.987629
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          1.6041028
 0.        ]
...
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]]

[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
 ...
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]]

...

[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
...
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
49.52598   ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
10.050183  ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          9.6911745
 0.        ]]
[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
...
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
29.483086  ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
24.422682  ]
[ 0.          0.          2.253025   ...  0.          0.
15.935954  ]]

[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.         ...  0.          0.
 0.        ]
[ 0.          0.         18.458588   ... 15.824303    0.
 0.        ]
 ...
[ 0.          0.          0.         ... 25.163502   56.87079
42.9939    ]
[ 0.          0.         11.397255   ... 36.644962   17.04247
44.108196  ]
[ 0.          0.         33.134758   ... 30.220499    8.817273
36.6427    ]]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, I believe you are confused how numpy works. If so, lets explain some things. An array from numpy is nothing but a string of bytes in memory. In particular, when those bytes are displayed for you, they are interpreted by a dtype. The dtype is not used to store the underlying data, but only to display it. Hence, changing the dtype only changes what the data looks like for you, it doesn't change the data itself. The same thing for the dimensions. The dimensions of the data only change how the data is displayed and accessed for you, python doesn't actually move the data around or change the data itself. For example,

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],dtype='int64') #48 bytes, each int takes up 8 bytes.
print(x)
x.dtype = 'int32'
print(x)
x.dtype = 'float'
print(x)
x.dtype = 'int16'
print(x)
```

Notice that we can change the dtype and absolute zero computation is done by the array (because the underlying data is already an array of bytes). Likewise we can change the shape and absolutely zero computation is done as well.

```
x.shape = (2,2,6)
print(x)
```

The shape and dtype have nothing to do with the stored data in memory. Hopefully this makes it clear how we can work with the array now as bytes.

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],dtype='int64')
print(x)
y = x.tobytes()

# Send y somewhere. Save to a file. Etc.

z = np.frombuffer(y)
z.dtype = 'int64'
z.shape = (2,3)
print(z)
```